# Xamarin SignalR client receive nothing from server

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, signalr

My mobile apps are based on Xamarin and receive some data from web server using SignalR. I've tried to use native Android port of SignalR client and JavaScript client and everything was fine.
But when I try to use SignalR Xamarin client app can connect to the server but receive empty response from the server. I've tried all kinds of fixes on client side but nothing helps me. I am sure that everything is fine on the server because everything works with another client.

Here is my server code:

```
    public DataMessage GetData()
    {
        var DataList = db.data.ToList();
        var DataIdList = new List<int>();
        db.Dispose();
        foreach (var a in DataList)
        {
            DataIdList.Add(a.id);
        }

        var result = new DataMessage(DataIdList);

        return result;
    }
```

And this is my app client code:

```
    async public Task<DataList> GetDataList()
    {
        DataList dataList = new DataList();
        Console.WriteLine(_hubConnection.State);
        if (_hubConnection.State == ConnectionState.Connected)
        {
            try
            {
                dataList = await _hubProxy.Invoke<DataList>("GetData");
                Console.WriteLine(dataList.data);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("SignalR Error GetDataList {0}", ex.Message);
            }
        }
        if (dataList == null)
        {
            dataList = new DataList();
        }
        return dataList;
    }
```

Can anybody help me with this issue?

Comment: Your method returns DataMessage but your invoke receives a DataList, are they the same class?

Comment: Yes, this is the same class on the client, it's just a layer, it contains only List with integers.